# Action of H2S and OH- on an alkyl halide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides

What would be the action of $\ce{OH-}$ and $\ce{H2S}$ on 2,6 dichloroheptane? I came across this question in my organic chemistry workbook but I have simply never seen a question of this type before. I think a cyclic compound may be formed, but I am not sure which.

I thought really hard with help from the comments under my question, I came up with this solution.  However in my book it says that there should be only one sulphur atom in the cyclic compound. How does this make sense as there are two halogens in the original haloalkane? Is my mechanism incorrect?

[image: my mechanism]

Comment: It rather depends on the reaction conditions, but the formation of 5 and 6-member rings is a favourable process and likely to occur, particularly with sulfide as a nucleophile

Comment: I assumed you mean $\ce{OH-}$ (like alkaline $\ce{H2S}$?)

Comment: @Waylander thank you! But why would there be a sulphide?

Comment: @Mathew Mahindaratne Yes.

Comment: H2S plus OH- gives HS- which will react readily with the haloalkane to give RSH, this will be further deprotonated by OH- to give RS- which will react internally to give the cyclic species.

Comment: @Waylander oh okay I get it! Thanks very much!

Comment: Please why has this question been down voted? I did research and could find no explanation on this forum.  Even on the general net, i could not find any explanation for the mechanism of this . Thank you.

Comment: Can this question please be put off hold? I have edited it.

Comment: It is unlikely you will get a cyclic disulfide as you have drawn. The second chloride is far more likely to be displaced by the internal nucleophile, that is the RS- already in the molecule. Redraw you mechanism with stepwise addition of sulfide.